# Black border div shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem with this shape, we are all ready using css border class to make this shape, please if any one can make this black box shape with in the Jquery. it will be very help.
me[image]

Comment: "One does not simply make it with jQuery"

Comment: I find the my answer here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504507/responsive-css-trapezoid-shape

Comment: Then flag this question as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You can use borders to create that shape and then just use `transform: rotate`

```css
.shape {
  width: 80px;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 80px solid black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: Boo, not enough jQuery! ;)